# How to validate password for user login

Tags: php, validation, authentication, pdo

```
<?php

include"database.php";

class User{
    public $db;


    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->db=new Database();
    }


    public function UserRegi($data){
        $name=$data['name'];
        $username=$data['username'];
        $email=$data['email'];
        $email_chk=$this->chkEmail($email);
        $password=md5($data['password']);


        if($name=="" || $username=="" || $email=="" || $password==""){
            $msg='<div class="alert alert-danger"><strong>Error ! </strong>Any Field Must Not Be Empty !</div>';
            return $msg;
        }
        if(strlen($username)<3){
            $msg='<div class="alert alert-danger"><strong>Error ! </strong>Username is too short !</div>';
            return $msg;
        }elseif(preg_match('/[^a-z0-9_-]+/i',$username)){
            $msg='<div class="alert alert-danger"><strong>Error ! </strong>Username Must be contain alpha numerical dashes and underscore  !</div>';
            return $msg;
        }
        if(filter_var($email,FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)===false){
            $msg='<div class="alert alert-danger"><strong>Error ! </strong>Invalid Email Address !</div>';
            return $msg;
        }elseif($email_chk==true){
            $msg='<div class="alert alert-danger"><strong>Error ! </strong>This Email Address Already Exists !</div>';
            return $msg; 
        }

        $sql="insert into tbl_user(name,username,email,password)values(:name,:username,:email,:password)";
        $query=$this->db->pdo->prepare($sql);
        $query->bindValue(":name",$name);
        $query->bindValue(":username",$username);
        $query->bindValue(":email",$email);
        $query->bindValue(":password",$password);
        $result=$query->execute();
        if($result){
            $msg='<div class="alert alert-success"><strong>Error ! </strong>Congrast User Registation successfull !</div>';
            return $msg; 
        }else{
            $msg='<div class="alert alert-danger"><strong>Error ! </strong>User Ragistation Failed !</div>';
            return $msg; 
        }


    }

    public function chkEmail($email){
        $sql="SELECT * FROM tbl_user WHERE email=:email";
        $query=$this->db->pdo->prepare($sql);
        $query->bindValue(":email",$email);
        $query->execute();
        if($query->rowCount()>0){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    } 


    public function userLogin($data){
        $email=$data['email'];
        $email_chk=$this->chkEmail($email);
        $password=md5($data['password']);
        $pass_chk=$this->chkPassword($email,$password);

        if(filter_var($email,FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)===false){
            $msg='<div class="alert alert-danger"><strong>Error ! </strong>Invalid Email Address !</div>';
            return $msg;
        }elseif($email_chk==false){
            $msg='<div class="alert alert-danger"><strong>Error ! </strong>This Email Address is not Exists !</div>';
            return $msg; 
        }
        if($pass_chk==true){
            $msg='<div class="alert alert-danger"><strong>Error ! </strong>Sorry Password incorrect !</div>';
            return $msg; 
        }

    }

    public function chkPassword($email,$password){
        $sql="SELECT * FROM tbl_user WHERE email=:email password=:password";
        $query=$this->db->pdo->prepare($sql);
        $query->bindValue(":email",$email);
        $query->bindValue(":password",$password);
        $query->execute();
        $result=$query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        if($result['password']==$password){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    } 

}


?>
```

It's showing this error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'password='d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e'' at line 1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\lr_new\lib\user.php:98 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\lr_new\lib\user.php(98): PDOStatement->execute() #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\lr_new\lib\user.php(77): User->chkPassword('', 'd41d8cd98f00b20...') #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\lr_new\login.php(10): User->userLogin(Array) #3 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\lr_new\lib\user.php on line 98

Comment: `email=:email password=:password`, this seems to lack `AND`

Comment: what i should use in this place

Comment: `email=:email AND password=:password` may help.

Comment: Like I said, `AND`. Read more [here](https://www.techonthenet.com/mariadb/where.php)

Comment: thanks i  can solve it now see i compare password in 100 line its show undefined how solve this plz

Comment: Can you add your class calling part with html please You should use php hash for password instead of mid5 https://www.php.net/manual/tr/function.password-hash.php

Comment: <?php
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]=="POST" && isset($_POST["login"])){
    $userLogin=$user->userLogin($_POST);
}

?>

<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <h2>User Login</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
      <div STYLE="max-width:600px;margin:0 auto ">
          <?php
          if(isset($userLogin)){
            echo $userLogin;
        }
          
          ?>
    
            <form action="" method="POST" >
                <div class="form-group">

Answer (score 0):

Your class is too complex and out of date, it needs to be rewriting almost half of it.
I will show you example which I use in my demo, I used my own settings and my own table structer.
Here is how you should call class :

```
require_once 'config.php';
require_once '../class/user.php';

$email = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'username', FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
$password = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'password', FILTER_DEFAULT);

if( $user->login( $email, $password) ) {
    die;
} else {
    $user->Msg();
    die;
}
```

And here your html codes of course in body tags, you probably using ajax so ne need action in form:

```html
<form method="POST">

<input type="text" id="username" name="username" value="dsdsd">
<input type="password" id="password" name="password" value="sdsd">
<input type="submit" name="LoginBtn" value="signup">
</form>
```

Your login function is to complex too, well your validating part is:

it should look like this :

```
public function login($email,$password){
    if(is_null($this->pdo)){
        $this->msg = 'Connection did not work out!';
        return false;
    }else{
        $pdo = $this->pdo;
        $stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT id, fname, lname, email, wrong_logins, password, user_role FROM users WHERE email = ? and confirmed = 1 limit 1');
        $stmt->execute([$email]);
        $user = $stmt->fetch();

        if(password_verify($password,$user['password'])){
                $this->user = $user;
                session_regenerate_id();
                $_SESSION['user']['id'] = $user['id'];
                $_SESSION['user']['fname'] = $user['fname'];
                $_SESSION['user']['lname'] = $user['lname'];
                $_SESSION['user']['email'] = $user['email'];
                $_SESSION['user']['user_role'] = $user['user_role'];
                return true;
        }else{
            $this->msg = 'Invalid login information or the account is not activated.';
            return false;
        } 
    }
}
```

Your register class should be up to date :

```
public function registration($email,$fname,$lname,$pass){
    $pdo = $this->pdo;
    if($this->checkEmail($email)){
        $this->msg = 'This email is already taken.';
        return false;
    }
    if(!(isset($email) && isset($fname) && isset($lname) && isset($pass) && filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))){
        $this->msg = 'Inesrt all valid requered fields.';
        return false;
    }

    $pass = $this->hashPass($pass);
    $confCode = $this->hashPass(date('Y-m-d H:i:s').$email);
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO users (fname, lname, email, password, confirm_code) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)');
    if($stmt->execute([$fname,$lname,$email,$pass,$confCode])){
        if($this->sendConfirmationEmail($email)){
            return true;
        }else{
            $this->msg = 'confirmation email sending has failed.';
            return false; 
        }
    }else{
        $this->msg = 'Inesrting a new user failed.';
        return false;
    }
}
```

And Here is password hashing:

```
private function hashPass($pass){
    return password_hash($pass, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
}
```

Comment: That's a good code in general. Just couple corrections. You should make the condition `if($user && password_verify($password,$user['password'])){` or it will throw an undefined index error at you. Also, `$_SESSION['user'] = $user;` will make your code look less cargo cult. Removing that useless `if(is_null($this->pdo)){` condition would do the same.

Comment: @YourCommonSense Thanks for points I will update answer, I check for sessions in pdo connection like so :  `public function __construct(\PDO $pdo){
        if(session_status() === PHP_SESSION_ACTIVE){
            try {
                $this->pdo = $pdo;
                return true;
            }catch(PDOException $e) { 
                $this->msg = 'Connection did not work out!';
                return false;
            }
        }else{
            $this->msg = 'Session did not start.';
            return false;
        }
    }` That is why I check `if(is_null($this->pdo)){`

Comment: `if(!(isset($email) && isset($fname) && isset($lname) && isset($pass)` is also useless because you just defined all these variables as the function's parameters, therefore they are **always** set.

Comment: Actulay this is a demo class here is the  original using one https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/234821/php-secure-remember-me-for-login-using-php-session-and-cookies-with-referer-url tought That is checking for emty values no ?`if(!(isset($email) && isset($fname) && isset($lname) && isset($pass) && filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))){` as I mention its a demo class in answer

Comment: Oh, a shame. I neglected my duty on codereview and here is the result. Gonna delete all comments from here and move them into an answer there.

Comment: @YourCommonSense sorry if I am been bad to you really sory. I am glad to hear your opinions on my codes and I am learning a lot on your comments, I will check my mistakes and try to make beter for next, and I am fan of you and funky four niner and dharman :)

Comment: Oh I see this is a made-up class that is quite different from the code you posted on codereview. May be you could write a real working code from this and post it as another question so I could review this as well?

Comment: @YourCommonSense promise I will, when I finished my project working on, and I will be glad to hear your opinions on my code review login too, if possible. Thanks